# How to scroll on the top of a page automatically on click on anchor tag?

Tags: jquery, magento

I have a website in magento
http://chpremier.com

In this website i noticed a small problem. Try this…

- from the menu, click on Fine Jewelry
- then click on AARON BASHA
- then scroll down and click on Necklaces..

notice that you see the loading icon, but no products.. you need to scroll back up to see the products. Can we have the page scroll all the way up automatically with jquery or anything else as i have only limited knowledge with magneto?

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#top">Go top</a>
$("a[href='#top']").click(function() {
          $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
          return false;
        });
```

Comment: Please provide a comment on your code snippet - what problem does it solve so that others can apply your solution in a similar situation

Comment: I have different "href" for different anchor tags you can see in above link